# Android LocationManager getLatitude() and getLongitude() numbers of decimal places

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I need to know more than six or seven decimal places when location is retrieved.
 Request

```
val fineCriteria = Criteria()

        fineCriteria.accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE
        fineCriteria.horizontalAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH
        fineCriteria.bearingAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH
        fineCriteria.isBearingRequired = true

        //val provider: String = locationManager!!.getBestProvider(fineCriteria, true)

        Log.e("LISTENER", "START LOCATION LISTENER $provider")
        locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(minTime, minDistance, fineCriteria,  locationListener, null)
```

and

```
private val locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
        Log.e("LOCATION", "onLocationChanged ${location!!.latitude} ${location!!.longitude} ${location!!.provider}")}
```

onLocationChanged 41.0629229 14.642092 here i need more decimals

Comment: "I need to known more then six or seven decimal places when get the location" -- 0.0000001 degrees is ~10 cm, which is already more precise than GPS supports.

Comment: thanks, and can compare two locations? because if i stay in the same place(no move) i retrieve always same coordinates, for me no differences